# Includes method ( n+ 1 issue ) doesn't work with a push method but does with += when assigning to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, performance, eager-loading

Consider the simple relation between Employee and Company models(many to many):

**Company model:**

```
has_many :employees, through: :company_employees
has_many :company_employees
```

**Employee model:**

```
has_many :companies, through: :company_employees
has_many :company_employees
```

**CompanyEmployee model(join table):**

```
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :company
```

also an **Owner model**:

```
has_many :companies
```

*So in my system i have an owner which may have several companies and an Employee, which may work for multiple companies.*

Now, In my employees **controller** i want to fetch all of the employees workin for an owner:

```
def owners_linked
 @company_employees = []
 owner.companies.each do |company|
   @company_employees.push (company.company_employees.includes(:company, :employee)) # when += instead of push - it works
 end
 respond_to do |format|
   format.js {render "employees_list"}
 end
end
```

I need to have an access to Employee instances(personal data), company_employees table (information about the position in the company) and Company(company related data).
To resolve **n+1 problem** and speed up the performance i use **includes** method. 
Well, the problem is that in my controller action in line:

```
@company_employees.push company.company_employees.includes(:company, :employee)
```

when using **push** method it doesn't work. I obtain the error in the view that employee method is not defined.
On the other hand when i change the push to **+=** sign it works perfectly fine.

Can anyone help me to understand why it's like so?
 I know that += is inefficint so i'd rather not stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with your use of includes.

When you use `+=` you end up with an array of `CompanyEmployee` objects. However when you use `push` you are no longer concatenating arrays but creating an array of collections. You are then calling `employee` on the collection rather than an element of the collection which is why you get an error.

Personally I would write this as

```
@company_employees = owner.companies.flat_map do |company|
  company.companee_employees.include(...)
end
```

Although I would do so for reasons of succinctness rather than performance. Any performance difference between `+=` and other ways of concatenating arrays is minuscule compared to the time it takes to fetch data from the database.

This doesn't entirely solve your n+1 problem though, since the data for each company is loaded separately. I would do

```
@company_employees = owner.companies.include(company_employees: [:company, :employee]).flat_map(&:company_employees)
```

Which doesn't do as many queries.

Answer (score 0):

I usually attack this by coming in from the other side. I believe this will get what you are looking for:

```
@company_workers = Employee.where(company_id: owner.companies.pluck(:id))
```

the `where(company_id: ...)` can take an array and automatically set it up to be an `in(...)` command in SQL.

So the SQL will end up being something like:

```
select * from employees where company_id is in(1,2,3,4)
```

With the 1, 2, 3, 4 are the owner's company IDs.